# Get included files - return include path not real path

Tags: php, linux, windows, include-path, php-include

On WINDOWS:

When i var_dump get_include_path

```
var_dump(get_included_files());
```

result it return is real path to file, for example:

```
array (size=2)
   0 => string 'C:\Users\svrcek\XAMPP\htdocs\folder\public\index.php' (length=52)
   1 => string 'C:\Users\svrcek\XAMPP\htdocs\folder\core\Bootstrap.php' (length=55)
```

Even if i don't change the inside script, only rename folder "public" to "Public", the included files directions change. That means, that what it returns is real path of file, not the way it is included. Problem is, when i transffer my app to Linux, casesensitivity broke my script.

Is there way how to get the way script include files and not the real path where file is?

Comment: You mean you want the relative path?

Comment: Let's look at file core/Bootstrap.php....on windows it doesn matter if include file as core/Bootstrap.php or Core/Bootstrap.php ... what i want to know which of these two ways the file was included in script ...